# Does $n$-dimensional convolution integral always exist

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables with densities $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$, then we know that the density of their sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is given by
$$
g(z)=\idotsint f_1 \left(x_1\right) f_2\left(x_2-x_1\right)\cdots f_n \left(z- \left(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1} \right)\right) \,dx_1 \cdots dx_{n-1}
$$

My doubt is that does $g(z)$ exist for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ ?

I could only prove that $g(z)$ is finite and hence well-defined for almost all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ using the fact that $\int g=1$.